# How can I properly sign my app in order to use task_for_pid() without getting error code 5?

Tags: macos, root, code-signing

I am developing a small application for macOS using C++ and Objective-C.
I want toscan the memory of other applications. In order to do that I am using **task_for_pid**.
But in most cases I get *error 5*.

How do I have to sign my app in order not to get this error?